# Custom Jquery Lightbox Plugin

Tags: jquery, lightbox, customization

This is my first plugin trying to create using the example provided [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery).

Now in the example there is a link where we can close the lightbox by clicking it.
But I want to know how do I Close it on clicking the background(ie..Anywhere on the webpage)

This is what I  have tried but it did not work.

```
 $('.paulund_block_page').click(function(){
          $(pop_up).fadeOut().remove();
 });
```

Can anyone say me where I went wrong?

Edit:This is the full plugin:

```
    (function($){

    // Defining our jQuery plugin

    $.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop){

        // Default parameters

        var options = $.extend({
            height : "250",
            width : "500",
            title:"JQuery Modal Box Demo",
            description: "Example of how to create a modal box.",
            top: "20%",
            left: "30%",
        },prop);

        return this.click(function(e){
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();

            $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();
        });

         function add_styles(){
            $('.paulund_modal_box').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'left':options.left,
                'top':options.top,
                'display':'none',
                'height': options.height + 'px',
                'width': options.width + 'px',
                'border':'1px solid #fff',
                'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
                'background': '#f2f2f2',
                'z-index':'50',
            });
            $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'-25px',
                'left':'20px',
                'float':'right',
                'display':'block',
                'height':'50px',
                'width':'50px',
                'background': 'url(images/close.png) no-repeat',
            });
                        /*Block page overlay*/
            var pageHeight = $(document).height();
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();

            $('.paulund_block_page').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0',
                'left':'0',
                'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                'height':pageHeight,
                'width':pageWidth,
                'z-index':'10'
            });
            $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
                'background-color':'#fff',
                'height':(options.height - 50) + 'px',
                'width':(options.width - 50) + 'px',
                'padding':'10px',
                'margin':'15px',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
            });
        }

         function add_block_page(){
            var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

            $(block_page).appendTo('body');
        }

         function add_popup_box(){
             var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
             $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

             $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
                $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut().remove();
             });
        }

        return this;
     };
 $('.paulund_block_page').click(function(){
       $(pop_up).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
       $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in that plugin that keeps it from working for me.

One of the lines says

```
'height':pageheight
```

when it should say

```
'height':pageHeight
```

(capitalize that h)

If you then insert your code into the bottom of the add_popup_box function it works fine. However, the fade out doesn't complete (it just disappears). Also, you forgot the code to remove the block page when you click the background.

Try this:

```
$('.paulund_block_page').click(function(){
    $(pop_up).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
    $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```

That will wait until the fade animation is complete before it removes the modal box and block page.

Update: You were adding the code to the wrong place. Here's what the plugin should look like:

```
(function($){

    // Defining our jQuery plugin

    $.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop){

        // Default parameters

        var options = $.extend({
            height : "250",
            width : "500",
            title:"JQuery Modal Box Demo",
            description: "Example of how to create a modal box.",
            top: "20%",
            left: "30%",
        },prop);

        return this.click(function(e){
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();

            $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();
        });

         function add_styles(){
            $('.paulund_modal_box').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'left':options.left,
                'top':options.top,
                'display':'none',
                'height': options.height + 'px',
                'width': options.width + 'px',
                'border':'1px solid #fff',
                'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
                'background': '#f2f2f2',
                'z-index':'50',
            });
            $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'-25px',
                'left':'20px',
                'float':'right',
                'display':'block',
                'height':'50px',
                'width':'50px',
                'background': 'url(images/close.png) no-repeat',
            });
                        /*Block page overlay*/
            var pageHeight = $(document).height();
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();

            $('.paulund_block_page').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0',
                'left':'0',
                'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                'height':pageHeight,
                'width':pageWidth,
                'z-index':'10'
            });
            $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
                'background-color':'#fff',
                'height':(options.height - 50) + 'px',
                'width':(options.width - 50) + 'px',
                'padding':'10px',
                'margin':'15px',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
            });
        }

         function add_block_page(){
            var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

            $(block_page).appendTo('body');
        }

         function add_popup_box(){
             var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
             $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

             $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
                $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
             });

             $('.paulund_block_page').click(function(){
                 $(pop_up).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
                 $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
             });
        }

        return this;
     };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @daxnitro-Thanks or your reply.I have included the part which you mentioned and tried but it still dosen't closes.

Comment: Check your error console. Are you getting any Javascript errors? If not, post the full plugin and I'll test it out.

Comment: I am not getting any errors and I have added the entire plugin code.

Comment: @daxnitro-Thanks for updating it and now I was into right drection :)